# Unable to send post requests to REST through HTTPClient

Tags: c#, rest, http, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

Quick question that I'm struggling to figure out.

I've got a REST Api up and running that works fine with **Postman** which I'm trying to figure out how to call with a Post-request from Xamarin Forms (using HTTPClient).

This is my current code:

```
    public CreateFoundation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblInstructions.FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
        lblInstructions.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label));

        btnCreate.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
            {
                var arb = await PostCreateFoundation(txtCreateFoundation.Text); 
                await DisplayAlert("Clicked", "I was clicked. Text was: " + arb, "OK");
            };
    }


    public async Task<string> PostCreateFoundation(string arbitrary)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("I'm in!");
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        var content = new StringContent(arbitrary); 

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://myapi.com/RestfulAPI/api/Ole_foundations/Insert/", content);

        var result = (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
        return result;


    }
```

When displaying the returned `string` (`arb`) I can see that the uri is `http://myapi.com/RestfulAPI/api/Ole_foundations/Insert/.`, regardless of what I send as the arbitrary string...

The resulting url when sending the string "test" is:

> {MESSAGE": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://myapi.com/RestfulAPI/api/Ole_foundations/Insert/'."}

EDIT:
The API takes an arbitrarily string as a token, adds a predefined object to the database and returns the passed in arbitrary string as a return token.

REST API function header:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Insert(string s)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was unsure if I should include the real API address or not, as it could be required for the 'minimal, verifiable example'.

Comment: What does the rest service supposed to return? Your last words are a bit confusing. Do you expect the url to change after the request?

Comment: The REST service simply returns a string, nothing else. I'm working with live data, so I pass in a string and want to have it back from the service. Like a token to ensure that a predefined object has been inserted into the databse.

Comment: well, it could be needed, the real url, if your question was directly related to that service. But instead you are struggling with post request implementation. Hence putting the real url is not the best idea.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Correct. Thanks for that though! :)

Comment: Alright. Are you expecting the url to change when you make your request? - As in `Get` requests, we put the parameters on the url.

Comment: No, not really. I mean, the URL will have "?s=" + the arbitrary string added to it before being sent as a POST request. But I assumed that would be handled by the StringContent.

Comment: Well, that's what I was trying to say. It won't happen. It's not how the data is passed to the server with `POST` requests.

Comment: So what is the actual response from the API? is arb empty?

Comment: The response will be the arbitrady string. 

I'll update the question with the function header.

Comment: Yes, but what does it actually return when you call it? `var result = (response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);`

Comment: Stepping through the debugger I get this from result: 

```{MESSAGE": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://myapi.com/RestfulAPI/api/Ole_foundations/Insert/'."}```

Answer (score 0):

When an action parameter is a simple type like a string, WebAPI assumes it should look for it in the query string. But you are passing it in the body. Try changing the method signature on the API side to:

```
public string Insert([FromBody]string s)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the final "/" on the uri

   Should be:

   http://myapi.com/RestfulAPI/api/Ole_foundations/Insert
2. Also what Todd Meiner said